# I build SwiftUI project and run it in the simulator. It shows only black screen

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I build a SwiftUI project and run it in the simulator. It only shows black screen.
Every single SwiftUI projects I downloaded it on the internet same black screen.
Even a new empty hello world project doesn't make difference.
A swift/objective-c project works normally.
What is the problem?

Comment: plz paste your code so we can reproduce.

Comment: I tried it with a different computer. It doesn't reproduce the same problem. Probably, it's just a Xcode version issue I guess. You can always try with a new empty SwiftUI project.

Comment: double check your macOS, xcode and simulator versions. i believe they need to be xcode 11.0+, simulator iOS 13.0+ and macOS catalina